# About finding advisors on the internet

Tags: soft-question

The thing is, since I do a job, and work on mathematics in my spare time, I do not have any connection with the academia. Secondly, the internet is the only way I can interact and reach out to other mathematicians or math enthusiasts like me.

If I need to discuss my paper with someone, where do I do so over the internet? (This is not about peer review, or about publishing my paper.)

Thats my question, more clearly:
**Where do I find people on the internet who can advise me on the papers that I write?**

OR

**Where I can discuss my papers on the internet?**

More specifically to give some background: I recently released a paper about a new zero-free region for Riemann Zeta Function http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.5572v14. I wish to get feedback about that. Do you know of any forums/groups, etc. where I can get a good and guiding response? Any links, forums, groups relevant to this topic would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Roupam

Comment: This is a difficult task. Have you tried to reach out to someone using e-mail?

Comment: I have tried before, but most are unresponsive. Maybe they are busy with their own schedules.

Comment: You might consider **paying** someone to read your paper.

Comment: @Robin:  Any suggestions on where to go to find someone to read a paper for pay?

Comment: @I.J.: The nearest university? At least, people in there can hook you up to somebody with the capability to evaluate your paper...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think randomly emailing professors is not going to earn any replies. Professors usually have a lot on their plate and they get hundreds of emails each day. Unsolicited emails are usually ignored.

One possibility you can explore is trying to establish email contact with a few graduate students in related areas. Once you have done this, you may send copies of your work to some of them and try to get feedback. You are more likely to find graduate students who are responsive and some of the advanced ones are actually used to reviewing papers.

EDIT: I found another useful piece on this subject by Henry Cohn
https://cohn.mit.edu/advice ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20230131190037/https://cohn.mit.edu/advice))